# X.PagedList.MVC namespace not available following NuGet install

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package, pagedlist

I'm trying to switch from [PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) to [X.PagedList](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList). I've used NuGet to uninstall the PagedList and PagedList.Mvc packages and then to install X.PagedList and X.PagedList.Mvc.

When I go to update my views, I find myself in a strange situation: I can't seem to reference the `PagedList.Mvc` namespace as detailed in [the example](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList#example) like this:

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc;
@using X.PagedList;
```

In Visual Studio and when debugging, this gives the following exception:

> The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace
>   'X.PagedList' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(*As an aside, if I leave off that `using`, I get exceptions about missing definitions, as expected.*)

Is there a problem with the NuGet package? Is there some way to manually add an assembly reference to a package installed via NuGet?

Comment: are you working on asp.net core application ? The documentation seems to specify that this doesn't work on .net core. I tried the same with sample application & everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: I don't think so, but I can't categorically say so. Looking at the other NuGet packages, I see Microsoft.AspNet rather than anything that looks like it might be .net core. Additionally, the target framework is set to .NET Framework 4.5. How could I tell for sure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, in the end I did find a hacky way to get this to work...

All I needed to do was manually add a reference to `X.PagedList.Mvc.dll`. Oddly, this was present in the packages directory (`.\packages\X.PagedList.Mvc.5.3.0.5300\lib\net46`) and has what looks to be a valid package file.

Not sure why this didn't happen automatically, but I'm suspicious that it was due to some conflict with the old `PagedList.Mvc` package.

Going to leave this question open for a week or two in case anyone can weigh in with something a little more insightful.

---

**UPDATE:** The approach above worked well locally, but failed when I deployed to test. This prompted a bit more digging and a resolution to get NuGet working properly.

I used the [NuGet package explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) to find out that `X.PagedList.Mvc` targets a more recent version of the .NET framework than the project I was adding it to (4.6 vs 4.5). Bit disappointed that the install didn't fail more helpfully, but at least its sorted now.